# IBM DB2 Community Edition Windows Requirement

Tags: db2-luw

I would like to install DB2 community edition on my Windows 10 PC. Does this require the Pro Edition of Windows or is the Home Edition sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility checks, much depends on exact versions of which products you want to use, and whether or not they are containerized.

Always read the accompanying materials, as much depends on whether you will deploy the Db2 product in a docker container or non-docker.  Docker itself will also have pre-requisites that will need checking.

In general the 'Home' edition is not supported by the *server* component (which is different from 'will not work'), and the 'Pro' editions of MS-Windows are preferred.

For IBM software products, there is a website that tries to help with compatibility reports of different product versions with different operating system versions.
Try running a report yourself, (requires some study of the notes in the result):

https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity/osForProduct.html